# Error - running app on device by android studio

Tags: android

im starting to proggraming on android studio,
and im trying to run my app on my LG G4

when i tring to "debug" ,the android studio recognize my device, and when i pick it i got an error :

> Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse

i dont have any other applacition running on my device, or eclipse on the computer.

when im trying to "Run" on regual mode(not debug) i see in the android monitor a lot of messages like "Decided to move IRQ51 from CPU3 to CPU0",
but nothing going on on my device.

i enabled usb debugging on my device.

you have any idea?
thanks.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: thank you for your respond,android studio

Answer (score 0):

I solved thats problem clicking on  Android Device Monitor Simbol.  Then the PID in the  Android Device Monitor change to "DEAD" and the Android debugger started.